# Finding the dimension of a subspace using Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help expressing the dimension of $S$ where
$$
S=\{ T\in Hom(V,V) | TJ=JT\}
$$
where $T$ and $J$ map from $V$ to $V$ and $V$ is $n$-dimensional vector space over field $F$. Also, $J$ is diagonalizable.

So far I have figured out that $S$ is a subspace of $Hom(V,V)$ and since $J$ is diagonalizable it has to be that it has $t_1...t_k$ distinct eigenvalues (it need not but for the sake of simplicity  lets say they are distinct) and $E_1...E_k$ distinct eigenspaces. Now one of my confusions is that is $J$ normal (i.e. $JJ^*=J^*J$,where $T=J^*$ is a masquerade)? If that is the case then using the spectral theorem: 
$dim(V)=n=\sum_1^k dim(E_i)$.

Additionally, if I am correct in assuming that $J$ is normal, then $T$ has eigenvalues $\bar{t_i}$ for $i=1,...,k$ and then $k$ eigenspaces corresponding to these eigenvalues. However, I am not entirely sure if this helps further the answer.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: Not every diagonalizable operator has distinct eigenvalues. Think about the identity operator. Also, $S$ is not a subspace of $V$, it is a subspace of $End(V)=Hom(V,V)$.

Comment: That's correct, yes. But for the sake of simplicity lets assume that $J$ has distinct eigenvalues. And as you said, $J$ is diagonal as well. But I don't see where to go from there.

Comment: Yeah, it's a subspace of $Hom(V,V)$, fixed that in the original question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know after that either. I just wanted to point that out. But I noticed that if $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $J$, then for any $T \in S$, the vector $Tv_i$ is also an eigenvector of $J$ with the same eigenvalue. So maybe the things in $S$ are precisely the things which preserve the eigenspaces of $J$.

Comment: Yup, thanks for that! :)

Comment: So, from my previous comment, I guess $\dim(S) = \sum_i \dim(E_i)^2$

Comment: 1. Not all diagonalizable matrices are normal, e.g. $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}$. 2. $\dim V=\sum_i \dim(E_i)$ doesn't require $J$ to be normal, it holds for every diagonalizable transformation.

Comment: Indeed, normalcy of $J$ is not even needed if we are just trying to show that $\dim(S)=\sum_i \dim(E_i)^2$. All we need is that it is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $J$ is diagonalizable, and decompose $V$ into a direct sum of eigenspaces of $J$, i.e, $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k E_i$.

I claim that $T \in S$ if and only if $T(E_i) \subset E_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$.

To prove this, suppose $T \in S$, and let $1\leq i \leq k$. Then for any $v \in E_i$, we have that $J(Tv) = T(Jv) = T(\lambda_i v) = \lambda_i Tv$, so that $Tv \in E_i$.

Conversely if $T(E_i) \subset E_i$ for all $i$, then for any $v \in V$  we can write $v = \sum_{i=1}^k v_i$ with $v_i \in E_i$, and so we have that $$T(Jv) = \sum_i T(Jv_i) = \sum_i T(\lambda_i v_i) = \sum_i \lambda_i Tv_i = \sum_i J(Tv_i) = J(T(\sum_i v_i)) = J(Tv)$$and thus $JT=TJ$.

Consequently, there is an isomorphism from $S \to \bigoplus_{i=1}^k Hom(E_i,E_i)$ given by $T \mapsto (T|_{E_1},T|_{E_2},...,T|_{E_k})$, where $T|_{E_i}$ denotes the restriction of $T$ to $E_i$.

It follows that $$\dim(S) = \sum_{i=1}^k \dim(Hom(E_i,E_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^k \dim(E_i)^2$$

Comment: Wow. This is brilliant! Thank you so much. :)